# How to fix const char is incompatible with type char DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I know this is a dumb question, but I'm trying to compile this code for a project, but I run into an error. I didn't write the code, my project is to modify it to get a different outcome than what the code was originaly suppose to produce.

However, I can't even start the project because the given code won't compile: Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *" Direct 3D Text  c:\Visual Studio Programs\Direct 3D Text\Direct 3D Text\D3DTextDemo.cpp 30

Code where I get the error:

```
bool D3DTextDemo::LoadContent()
{
    ID3DBlob* vsBuffer = 0;

    bool compileResult = CompileD3DShader("TextureMap.fx", "VS_Main", "vs_4_0", &vsBuffer);

    if (compileResult == false)
    {
        DXTRACE_MSG("Error compiling the vertex shader!");
        return false;
    }

    HRESULT d3dResult;

    d3dResult = d3dDevice_->CreateVertexShader(vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
    vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, &solidColorVS_);

    if (FAILED(d3dResult))
    {
        DXTRACE_MSG("Error creating the vertex shader!");

        if (vsBuffer)
            vsBuffer->Release();

        return false;
    }

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC solidColorLayout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };

    unsigned int totalLayoutElements = ARRAYSIZE(solidColorLayout);

    d3dResult = d3dDevice_->CreateInputLayout(solidColorLayout, totalLayoutElements,
        vsBuffer->GetBufferPointer(), vsBuffer->GetBufferSize(), &inputLayout_);

    vsBuffer->Release();

    if (FAILED(d3dResult))
    {
        DXTRACE_MSG("Error creating the input layout!");
        return false;
    }

    ID3DBlob* psBuffer = 0;

    compileResult = CompileD3DShader("TextureMap.fx", "PS_Main", "ps_4_0", &psBuffer);

    if (compileResult == false)
    {
        DXTRACE_MSG("Error compiling pixel shader!");
        return false;
    }

    d3dResult = d3dDevice_->CreatePixelShader(psBuffer->GetBufferPointer(),
    psBuffer->GetBufferSize(), 0, &solidColorPS_);

    psBuffer->Release();

    if (FAILED(d3dResult))
    {
        DXTRACE_MSG("Error creating pixel shader!");
        return false;
    }

    d3dResult = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(d3dDevice_,
    "font.dds", 0, 0, &colorMap_, 0);

    if (FAILED(d3dResult))
    {
        DXTRACE_MSG("Failed to load the texture image!");
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: The error message is quite clear I think. It would be even clearer if you somehow told us on *which line* you get the error. Please edit your question to add a comment on that line.

Comment: It doesn't help that he hasn't included the definition of the 'CompileD3DShader' function either, but if it's defined in the same way as similar code I can find online, then it's defined to take char* arguments, whereas the string literals being passed will be const. If the function doesn't modify these then it should probably be changed to take them as const.

Answer (score 2):

A char* defined in double quotes -eg.`"TextureMap.fx"`- is called a string literal and is per definition constant.
When you pass a constant value to a function that takes non-constant values, there is no guarantee that it won't be modified and thus won't compile.

I fixed this issue by defining the literal in a char[], which doesn't make it constant anymore:

```
char fxFile[] = "TextureMap.fx";
bool compileResult = CompileD3DShader(fxFile, "VS_Main", "vs_4_0", &vsBuffer);
```

Comment: Of course a better fix would be to make ``CompileD3DShader`` take ``const`` since the underlying D3DCompile APIs take ``const``. And really for filenames you should be using UNICODE and taking ``const wchar_t*``.